# Can I "run" spring context without writing any code in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I can run JUnit test in Eclipse despite it has no `main()` method. I can run Ant xml despite it has no any code.

Can I run Spring context in the same way?

Can I instruct Eclipse to quickly run the program like below on spring XML "runing"?

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/springtests/test04.xml");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This question is about comfort. I am writing a lot of tests for spring configurations. For each test I am writing either JUnit test or a runner class like above. So I want to minimize effort: to be able to right click XML file with spring configuration and "run" it. By "running" I don't mean loading XML into memory and transfering CPU control to it.

**UPDATE 1**

Ok I created `SpringRunner` class in my project with the following code

```
public class SpringRunner {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(args[0]);
}
}
```

next created Run/Debug configuration with the name `SpringRunner` and this calss as main class, and set

```
${resource_loc}
```

in the program arguments section.

This way I can "run" any spring config with few clicks:

1) Right click XML file

2) Select "Run/Debug As..."

3) Select "Run/Debug Configurations..."

4) Select "SpringRunner"

5) Click "Run/Debug"

Now the question is if it is possible to shorten this more? How to tell Eclipse to show this option on to any XML file or to any file at all immediately on right-click and "run/debug as"?

Comment: You don't *run* XML, you *process* XML.

Comment: You don't run anything then, you process it. And the core of the computer is called "processor" but not "runner".... My question was not about terminology...

Comment: If you think terminology isn't important there's a problem: Spring config files are just that; configuration. If you're not willing to take whatever advice people give, the internet is going to be a scary, frustrating place.

Comment: There are no scary and frustrating places, but there are scary and frustrating people ;)

Comment: You obviously don't climb or cave dive, then.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can never do it even with JUnit, .... When you run JUnit, internally it has some util class that has main method, this method runs your junit classes by reflection.

Just remember, There is not way in java that you can run any code without main method.

```
class A{
       static{
              System.out.print("where is main");
       }

}
```

this code works when class loaded into jvm, This maybe exception to my above words, But general answer is NO.

Quick question why do you need to run spring without main? 
If you consider junit is runnig without main method(actually It has), then use app container like tomcat, you do not have to declare any main method, It runs your code, your spring or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html#testcontext-framework

**for example:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
// ApplicationContext will be loaded from "/applicationContext.xml" and "/applicationContext-test.xml"
// in the root of the classpath
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/applicationContext.xml", "/applicationContext-   test.xml"})
public class MyTest {
// class body...
```

}

hope I could help...